# What's the maximum number of regions that can be monitored on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-location

Any one know what's the maximum number of shared regions is? Do you get regionMonitoringDidFail call if you exceed it?

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/monitoredRegions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't get it to accept more than 10 regions. No error message just monitoredRegions does not get any members after 10.

edit: if I add a lot (around 60) of regions sometimes it crashes. No error message. This produces a bad access

```
[locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:clr desiredAccuracy:500.0];
```

edit: at 5 regions I am getting pretty reliable results

Comment: Thanks, I get somewhere around 10, other times it's less. I kind of feel like this API is not ready for primetime. I also sometimes get some wierd "failing to copy" type message in the log when debugging, but and my monitoredRegions count will be 0. Ah well.

Comment: thanks for the comment I am having the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029293/startmonitoringforregion-not-always-adding-regions-to-monitoredregions

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience. Here are a few tips:

1. You need to check `@selector(locationManager:monitoringDidFailForRegion:withError:)` in delegate at each time.
2. Keep the radius smaller than `maximumRegionMonitoringDistance`.